# Was never asked to set a password, can't download software without one?

Tags: password

I installed chrubuntu on my ARM chromebook. I need to download from the Ubuntu software center. Whenever I try to download something, it asks for authentication by a password, but I have never set one or was ever asked to set one. Is there a default password or is something weird going on with this? I've tried spacebar, blank, "chronos", "user"

Comment: Have you tried setting a user password with the command ''passwd'' from the Terminal? Then you should be able to use the sudo command to install software.

Comment: For everyone voting to close this, [ChrUbuntu is on topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7095/chrubuntu-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic).

Comment: @Alaa are you sure? it's not listed [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) as an official derivative.

Comment: @WarrenHill yup, I know it's not listed there, but click on the "ChrUbuntu is on topic" link in my comment =).

Comment: @Alaa but in this case we seem to see a problem with the installation, don't we? So still off-topic.

Comment: I agree with @guntbert. Password is set at installation time and the ChrUbuntu installation is very much different compared to installation of the regular Ubuntu version. Therefore the meta post with the reasoning that ChrUbuntu is on-topic in most cases does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

The password that it asks for is the password you use to login, which is the same password you set when you were installing Ubuntu. If you've set that password before, enter it.

If you haven't set a password during installation, you can set your password now. Follow the below steps:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Type `passwd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type in a new password. You will not see anything when you type, just continue on typing and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Confirm the password again.

That's it; you have now set a password for your account. Now go try to install, and enter that password when prompted. This password will also be the password you use when you boot your Ubuntu.

Comment: I was never asked to create a password. When I use the terminal, it asks for my current unix password, but I didn't set one! I can't create my own without first entering this one, whatever the heck it is